How do add path to a folder in my jupyter notebook
I am working on a code that converts pdf file to image file without compromising image quality, and require poppler to work with pdf2image module but apparently I am running the code on an online server that my company provides that runs jupyter notebook on my browser. So adding the path to the poppler bin file or adding thr path to my environment variable is not possible. My code successfully installs and unzips the poppler file from a github repository.
Please Instruct me on how should I modify the code to get the path to the poppler bin folder in order to use the resources and for the code to run.
#%%
import fitz
from PIL import Image
import wget
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
#%%

#this will install poppler file
zip_url = "https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/download/v24.02.0-0/Release-24.02.0-0.zip"
zip_filename = wget.download(zip_url)

# unzips poppler file
!unzip -o {zip_filename}
#%%

# Below is the code to extract lines from a pdf file

doc = fitz.open("table.pdf")
page = doc[0]
paths = page.get_drawings()  # extract existing drawings
# this is a list of "paths", which can directly be drawn again using Shape
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
#%%
# define some output page with the same dimensions
outpdf = fitz.open()
outpage = outpdf.new_page(width=page.rect.width, height=page.rect.height)
shape = outpage.new_shape()  # make a drawing canvas for the output page
#%%
# --------------------------------------
# loop through the paths and draw them
# --------------------------------------
for path in paths:
    # ------------------------------------
    # draw each entry of the 'items' list
    # ------------------------------------
    for item in path["items"]:  # these are the draw commands
        if item[0] == "l":  # line
            shape.draw_line(item[1], item[2])
        elif item[0] == "re":  # rectangle
            shape.draw_rect(item[1])
        elif item[0] == "qu":  # quad
            shape.draw_quad(item[1])
        elif item[0] == "c":  # curve
            shape.draw_bezier(item[1], item[2], item[3], item[4])
        else:
            raise ValueError("unhandled drawing", item)
    # ------------------------------------------------------
    # all items are drawn, now apply the common properties
    # to finish the path
    # ------------------------------------------------------
    shape.finish()
#%%

shape.commit()
outpdf.save("test_file_ext2.pdf")
#%%

pdf_path = 'test_file_ext.pdf'
doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
#%%

# poppler-24.02 ->Library -> bin -> copy path and paste path below
poppler_path = r'C:\Users\KIIT\OneDrive\Desktop\Project_Folder\poppler-24.02.0\Library\bin'  
images = convert_from_path(pdf_path, poppler_path=poppler_path)
# Save each image as a JPEG file
for image in images:
    image.save('extracted_image1.jpg', 'JPEG')

Since I cant install files from the internet on my local system i used the wget command to install the poppler file on the online server i can see the folder and all other files that come with it, but apparently I have no idea on how I can get the path to the bin Folder so as to use it in my code.The code run perfectly on my personal computer since I have all the admin access and can edit my environment variables and install the folder on my laptop to get the bin path but am unable to do the same on my corporate laptop the poppler folder get stored on their online server and just shows me "Project_Folder / poppler-24.02.0 / bin" upon copying this in my code it dosen't work.
Help me to get the path to the poppler folder and use it in the code, also suggest me on how I can automatically Insert the bin path in the code so that other people using my code will not have to manually change the path according to their system.

you can use import os module to handle the directory paths dynamically.
so you won't require to add the proper or manual path.
Thankyou.
Rajat Mishra

will it work on folders stored online? like on the cloud usually people copy path of a folder by opening it in file explorer.

Hey, As i can see the zip URL you can use the "import zipfile" and  define the extraction path and unzip it using with "zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'r') as zip_ref:
zip_ref.extractall(extraction_path)" then determine the path and verify that the path exists.
